# How to use a custom OdeSolver in Scipy's solve_ivp

Tags: numerics, ode, scipy, integration

In [Scipy's `solve_ivp` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), we see the `method` argument can be either a string or a user-defined `OdeSolver` inherited from `scipy.integrate._ivp.base` ([source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/701ffcc8a6f04509d115aac5e5681c538b5265a2/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py)). I tried to create my own `OdeSolver` class and pass it into `solve_ivp` as follows:

```
from scipy.integrate._ivp.base import OdeSolver 

### not actually changing anything here
class MyOdeSolver(OdeSolver):
  def __init__(self, fname, lname):
      super().__init__(fname, lname)

sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(ODEs, time_span, 
      initial_conditions,method=MyOdeSolver)
```

and got the error

```
553         method = METHODS[method]
    554 
--> 555     solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
    556 
    557     if t_eval is None:

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vectorized'
```

I have been searching online about how to use a custom-defined `OdeSolver` with `solve_ivp`, but couldn't find any example. If anyone can show me an example, it would be great!

Comment: This looks like it should be a bug report. But does the base class implement a method or is it just abstract? Does it work when you import the RK45 and use that class instead of the string in `method`?

Comment: On reading the documentation, how did you get the idea to use only `fname, lname` as parameters, what are they anyway? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.OdeSolver.html#scipy.integrate.OdeSolver gives detailed instructions on how to implement your own solver, I do not see such parameters involved. You need to code a `_step_impl` and `_dense_output_impl` and also `_call_impl` in the dense output class, where the calculation happens. These are stubs with `raise NotImplementedError` in the base classes.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is entirely normal. You should be giving a OdeSolver subclass (e.g. scipy.integrate.RK45) which implements the correct interface. In particular, the OdeSolver class is not meant to be instantiated directly. It is for example missing a few arguments in the init function, which is why you get this error. The documentation of solve_ivp will tell you how to implement your own solver.